# How can I obtain the reference of an Activity using ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When I code：`Activity activity = (Activity)context;`,here context is a type of ApplicationContext.
It tells me  I can't cast applicationContext to Activity.
So,how can I get the reference of activity just knowing the reference of ApplicationContext?

Comment: use getActivity() instead of context

Comment: please share some code

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this directly, but you can implement the interface ActivityLifecycleCallbacks in your Application class, and use those methods to keep track of the current Activity.

Then you can implement a "getCurrentActivity()" method in your Application class.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationContext` is not the context of an Activity. It is the context of the `Application` class that you define in Manifest. So you can't cast it to an activity.